# Drop down menu to sensitive

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple drop down menu on my website. I am trying to get it so when I hover over the About Me tab it drops down a menu which has "contact me" there. I have it working, but the issue is even when I put my mouse on the same line as the navigation bar it appears, so if I hover over Home, it appears. I just want it to appear when hovering over about me.

Here is my css and html

```
#nav{
   width: 75%;
   height: 3%;
   font-size: 150%;
   font-weight: bold;
   border-radius: 8%;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav ul {
   height: auto;
   padding: 0% 0%;
   margin: auto%;
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
   border-bottom: 5% solid #ccc; 
   display: inline-block;
   overflow: hidden;
}

#nav li { 
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 3%; 
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}

#nav a {
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;
}

#nav a:hover {
   color: #000000;
   background-color: white;
}

#aboutme:hover ul {
   display: block;
}

#nav li ul {
   display: none;
}

#nav li:hover ul{
   display: block;
}

    <ul id="nav">
       <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="kotorsale.html">For Sale</a></li>
      <li><a href="buildlog.html">Build Log</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: I tested your code and wasn't able to recreate this phenomenon.  http://jsfiddle.net/JzvbU/.  Maybe there is some additional code that you didn't show?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new mark-up to correct some of your issues.  Hope this helps you.  Also, I change the nav element to a class from ID.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="kotorsale.html">For Sale</a></li>
    <li><a href="buildlog.html">Build Log</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 750px;
    text-align: center; 
}
ul.nav, ul.nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 115px;
}
ul.nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;  
}
ul.nav li ul li {           
    width: 155px;           
    text-align: left;       
    padding: 15px;          /*--------UPDATE--------*/
}
ul.nav li ul li a {         /*--------UPDATE--------*/
    padding: 15px;          /*--------UPDATE--------*/
}
.nav li:hover ul {
    left: auto;
}
ul.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em .5em;
}
ul.nav li li a {
    border-top: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
}
ul.nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is an example in JSFiddle: (jsfiddle.net/5GBt2/13)

Comment: I tried, but then the nav bar isnt centered like it was, can i just go ahead and center myself? Dont want to screw the hover effect up

Comment: You can, it should not effect the hover effect.

Comment: best to center just by using margins? i tried but then for some reason I also set width, however then like About Me is on 2 lines, instead of one. If I could center and get long words like build log and about me to be one line and not 2 id be good

Comment: I  updated the code to reflect the necessary changes to prevent the links from dropping down to next line.  Here is the JSFiddle file with the corrections: (http://jsfiddle.net/5GBt2/6/http://jsfiddle.net/5GBt2/6/)  Hope this helps.

Comment: ok got it working, was pasted twice hehe. Thanks for the help, for some reason still not centered, can i do that using position abolsute? should work well enough right? or just margins

Comment: ok i see, when i increase font size to 250% it makes the long titles go on 2 lines, is there a way to stop that?

Comment: Okay, most of your issues are addressed.  Here is the update JSFiddle:  (http://jsfiddle.net/5GBt2/9/).  I also updated my original response.

Comment: Thanks man, one last thing, can i change the width of the Contact Me Drop down sub menu, or not easily?

Comment: All set Terry, updated the original correspondence and the JSFiddle file.  Here is the new link: (
Here is an example in JSFiddle: (http://jsfiddle.net/5GBt2/11/)

Comment: Thank you, can i just increase padding now to make the space between about me and its sub menu greater? Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes you can.  Same line:     (ul.nav li ul li)

Comment: however than, the sub menu dissapears before u can move the mouse from about me to contact me :(

Comment: i will just use .3em padding top, sub menu stays, hehe. Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: How much padding did you give it?  I gave it 15px and it is still ok.

Comment: Ok.  I see what you are talking about.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Just match the padding for both (ul.nav li ul li) and the NEW (ul.nav li ul li a)

Comment: ah OK thank you very much for all your help. going to bed but I really appreciate it. sorry for all the questions lol nav bar are always hard for me.